# Crontab não executa função PHP do arquivo no diretório

Tags: php, linux

Estou executando o seguinte código no Servidor Linux via Putty da Digital Ocean

Dentro do Crontab-e

Esta assim

```
01 00 * * * /var/www/html/atualizador/atualizador-global.php

* * * * * /usr/bin/php7.3 http://www.sistemasjca.com.br/atualizador/cronteste.php

mailto="andrews@jcacontadores.com.br"
```

Entretando o código PHP não executa dentro deste arquivo cronteste.php estou executando um código para inserir uma linha no banco de dados, porém nao tenho retorno de nada, quando olho no banco de dados não foi inserido e também nao recebo email sobre a execução.

Também tentei executar assim

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/html/atualizador/atualizador-global.php
```

O código de teste que estou tentando executar é o seguinte.

```
require_once("conexao-com-banco-users.php");
testaCron($conecta_login);

function testaCron($conecta){
    $query_bancos = "INSERT INTO banco_usuarios.tbl_usuarios(funcionario, usuario, email, senha, imagem) VALUES('CronjobUser','CronjobUser','CronjobUser','CronjobUser', '8D')";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conecta, $query_bancos);

    if($resultado)
        echo 'usuario inserido com sucesso';
}

?>
```

Este é o log que fui puxado via  "grep CRON /var/log/syslog"
[image: nux]

Comment: Quer que o PHP acesse uma pagina remota?

Comment: não quero rodar um código php pelo lado servidor sem envolver o front end esse código basicamente insere um dado no banco de dados

Comment: Mas a execução do teu comando esta assim, por isso perguntei. Não tem haver com front-end, na verdade comando de linha nem interage com o navegador, a não ser que vc queira, mas ai é "outros 500", se quer que a pagina processe é WGET, se o script esta no mesmo servidor e falhou é pq tem alguma coisa errada no script, provavelmente.

Answer (score 1):

|PROBLEMA RESOLVIDO|Entrando como usuário Root no putty via SSH

No terminal botei

```
sudo apt-get install php7-cli
```

Após isso entrei com

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Dentro do crontab chamei meu arquivo php desta forma.

```
* * * * * php /var/www/html/Atualizador/cronteste.php
```

Após estes passos registrou os dados corretamente no banco via Script no crontab.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Até aonde sei o comando de linha `php` não acessa páginas remotas, ou se acessa precisa provavelmente liberar no php.ini o `allow_url_fopen`, ainda sim não necessáriamente executaria, aliás executaria no servidor, porque é uma requisição HTTP e depois teria pegar a "resposta do HTTP" e executar na sua máquina, o que seria uma bela chance de atacar a maquina com códigos maliciosos.

Resumindo, nada disso ai faz sentido, se é para acessar uma URL esterna o correto é usar `wget` e configurar assim no crontab:

```
* * * * * wget 'http://www.sistemasjca.com.br/atualizador/cronteste.php'
```

---

Agora se isto não esta funcionando:

```
 * * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/html/atualizador/atualizador-global.php
```

É porque pode ser algum erro no script, talvez seja isto o que espera:

```
 * * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/html/atualizador/cronteste.php
```

Comment: * * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/html/Atualizador/cronteste.php

Eu coloco assim , mas não executa pode ser o PHP que esta numa pasta diferente como posso saber

o script roda localmente

Comment: @AndrewsGomes Mas o log do PHP emite algo? Sabe configurar o log do PHP no php.ini? Pois como eu disse, pode ser erro no seu script PHP.

Comment: No PHP ele da sucesso na operação ele inclui o registro no banco corretamente quando eu chamo o arquivo diretamente do php coloco localhost/atualizador/cronteste.php e ele me retorna um echo dizendo que foi inserido com sucesso.

eu vi na internet essa possibilidade tambem * * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/sistemasjca.com.br/atualizador/cronteste.php > /dev/null 2>&1
 
mas nao sei se estou fazendo errado

Comment: @AndrewsGomes bem ... não tem como ficarmos especulando, use as ferramentas que tem a seu favor, os LOGs, vá no php.ini, configure os logs para um arquivo ou email e execute o CRON novamente, depois vá no log e veja o que ele coletou.